# Obtener día hábil anterior en una consulta SQL en Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Requiero traer el **día hábil anterior** en una **consulta SQL en Oracle**.

1. Si el **día anterior es Domingo**, debería mostrar **Viernes**.
2. Si el **día anterior es un Martes Festivo**, debería mostrar **Lunes**.
3. Etc.

¿Cómo sería esa consulta? De momento tengo lo siguiente:

```
SELECT TO_DATE(to_char(sysdate, 'YYYYMMDD'), 'YYYYMMDD')-1 FROM DUAL;
```

Como pueden ver, trae el día anterior, pero incluyendo días no hábiles. Por lo tanto, no es una solución al problema que requiero.

Agradezco su atención.

Comment: Es una pregunta chévere. La debería seguir esta pregunta: cómo podría saber Oracle cuáles son los festivos de un país? :)

Comment: Empecemos mucho antes.. como sabes, en tu consulta, el dia que es esa fecha???

Comment: @gbianchi te refieres a los días fines de semana/festivos? O te refieres al día actual?

Comment: al actual, el que devuelve ese query...

Comment: @gbianchi devuelve el día anterior, 15/3/2022

Comment: y ya sabes que dia de la semana es ese?

Comment: @gbianchi puedo utilizar la consulta SELECT TO_CHAR(SYSDATE-1, 'DAY') AS DAY FROM DUAL; para saber que día corresponde

Comment: muy bien.. si lo pones en un case, podes filtrar si es sabado o domingo e ir para atras, no?